# PropertiesConfiguration how to reference config.properties

Tags: apache, configuration, configuration-files

I am new to Java so forgive me for my lack of knowledge. I am trying to utilize a properties file in my web app.  While researching I found this article http://commons.apache.org/configuration/howto_properties.html  which seemed pretty straight forward so I attempted to implement this.  I attempted to implement as follows :

```
    Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("stream.bundle.config");
```

I have tried stream.bundle.config, bundle.config and many other combinations but every time I get back an exception that says Cannot locate configuration source.  The file is in a folder under src called bundle.  My question is a) where should the file be?  b) how should I reference it. I apologize for my lack of knowledge. Thanks in advance.

update:

I also tried

```
        FileInputStream in; 
    Properties p = new Properties();

    try{
        in  = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        p.load(in);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
```

and I get java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (The system cannot find the file specified) or java.io.FileNotFoundException: config (The system cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding a) where should the file be:

- in the current directory
- in the user home directory
- in the classpath

If you consider using Java's [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) you have to get an InputStream some way. If you're loading the properties from a class in the package, you have to use:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("resource.properties");
```

and if the class is in another package:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("some/pkg/resource.properties");
```

You can try loading the properties via the ClassLoader:

```
ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream ("some/pkg/resource.properties");
```

If you have a ServletContext, you can use:

`ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(..)`

EDIT: you should reference your file by the full name (filename+extension). So your first
try should have been:

```
Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("config.properties");
```

Comment: How do I then pass that to PropertiesConfiguration()?

Comment: I thought it was not necessary to stick to apache's PropertiesConfiguration. You may consider using Java's Properties: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: Ok, just to clarify my file is in build/classes/stream/bundle  and the file is config.properties.   To access I should be able to write: getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");  ? Also thanks for all your help!

Comment: you should have reference your file by filename+extension. So you may re-try your initial approach. I edited my answer to see how it should look.

Comment: that gives me  Cannot locate configuration source config.properties

Comment: Than I suggest you try the Java Properties class. Maybe start with a simple project with just this file, but the same package structure, and try to load it and read properties from it, following an example - there's plenty of examples on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try 
{
    properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xyz.properties"));
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```